# linear independence of vector functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

would the below vector functions be linearly independent? Even though the wronskian is equal to 0?

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & t & t\\ 2t^2 & 2t^3 & 3t^2\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What are the functions?

Comment: @copper.hat I assume they are $$t \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2t^2\end{bmatrix}, \quad t \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}0\\t\\2t^3\end{bmatrix}, \quad t \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}0\\t\\3t^2\end{bmatrix}$$
for $t \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid: Its part of my ineffective rhetorical nudging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions are linearly independent.

Assume that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \Bbb{R}$ are such that
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \alpha\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2t^2\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}0\\t\\2t^3\end{bmatrix}+\gamma\begin{bmatrix}0\\t\\3t^2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\\alpha + (\beta+\gamma)t\\(2\alpha+3\gamma)t^2 + 2\beta t^3\end{bmatrix}$$
for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$. This is equivalent to $$\alpha + (\beta+\gamma)t = 0, \quad (2\alpha+3\gamma)t^2 + 2\beta t^3, \quad \forall t \in \Bbb{R}$$
These polynomials are zero so their coefficients must be $0$ as well. It follows:
$$\alpha = \beta + \gamma = 2\alpha + 3\gamma = 2\beta = 0$$
which implies $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$.

Comment: So even though vector 2 is just vector a * t, we can't set $\alpha$ to be t, only to a scalar, correct?

Comment: @ajm456 Yes. If $\alpha$ could depend on $t$, then you could say that any two functions $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ are dependent, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That matrix is, as maximum, a rank $2$ matrix. So we can say its column vectors are not linearly independent since it's a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Comment: You’ve fallen into this exercise’s trap: Linear independence of a set of functions is not equivalent to linear independence of all of their corresponding values. That’s like saying that $(1,1)$ and $(2,3)$ are linearly dependent because $2\cdot1-1\cdot 2=0$ and $3\cdot 1-1\cdot 3 = 0$.